# InternetSetCookie does not store cookie in Temporary Internet Files

Tags: c#, cookies, wininet

I'm trying to create a cookie on client side using wininet from a c# winform application.
So I use this code:

```
[DllImport("wininet.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]  
public static extern bool InternetSetCookie
(
    string lpszUrlName, 
    string lbszCookieName, 
    string lpszCookieData
);

private void btnRestaure_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        var result = InternetSetCookie("www.mydomain.com", "MyCookie",
                              "value=helloworld");
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

`InternetSetCookie` returns me true but I can't find the cookie in the **Temporary Internet Files** folder.
Any clue ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think if you don't specify an expiration date then you create a session cookie. If you want a persistent cookie try specifying an expiration date.

I assume that such a cookie is only stored in RAM and not serialized to disk. And most likely only visible to your own process.

---

If you check the [MSDN documentation for InternetSetCookie](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385107(v=vs.85).aspx) you see:

> Cookies created by InternetSetCookie without an expiration date are stored in memory and are available only in the same process that created them. Cookies that include an expiration date are stored in the windows\cookies directory.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was exactly my issue. I believe I should read docs a bit more carrefully next time :p

Comment: @BrunoLeDuic did you find the way how to write in folder with expiration?

Comment: @CodeInChaos can you tell please how to store it in disk?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad Probably by specifying an expiration date. But I've never used that API myself, so I don't know the details. "Cookies that include an expiration date are stored in the windows\cookies directory."